# Difference of multiple Gaussian random variables with unknown assignment

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

Suppose I have two samples from two Normal distributions and I want to construct a test to decide if my two sets of samples come from the same underlying joint distribution. Let's say I know the variances for simplicity. If I know which sample comes from which Normal distribution then a simple test might be based on
$$
(X_1 - Y_1)^2 + (X_2 - Y_2)^2
$$
Which if the variances are added in there (forgive my formatting, I'm on mobile and will fix later ...) is distributed as chi^2 with 2 degrees of freedom under the hypothesis that the samples come from the same distribution. Which seems like a good start.

However, suppose now that I *don't* know which sample in each pair comes from which Normal distribution. I could construct a test like the above for all possible combinations, but then I am doing multiple tests and have to deal with some kind of multiple testing corrections probably. And I don't really care which sample is which, I just want to test if the two sets of samples come from the same (joint) distribution.

Is there a way to improve the simple chi-square based test to achieve what I want, preferably keeping the null distribution as something relatively simple? Bonus points if it works for samples of unequal length. The most naive thing is probably something like
$$
(X_1 - Y_1)^2 + (X_2 - Y_2)^2 + (X_1 - Y_2)^2 + (X_2 - Y_1)^2
$$
(appropriately scaled by variances ...) however the different terms there are going to be correlated in some gnarly way that probably makes this a bad idea. I guess there is a more principled approach that might lead to an answer along these lines though ...

Comment: How could samples have "unequal length" when your data explicitly are constituted by "pairs"??  Something is contradictory here: please explain.

Comment: The standard test if you know which observations come from which sample is the two-sample t-test (can be done as a z-test if variance is known). Your formula summing up $(X_i-Y_i)^2$ suggests that the samples may be *paired*, i.e., observations with the same index are connected with each other. This however looks different to me from what you describe, so I suspect your wording doesn't explain clearly what the situation actually is. Are you saying data are paired but you don't know what the pairs are?

Comment: One idea: if indeed you don't have pairs, but just have a bunch of data and you suspect they might have been generated by two different Normal distributions, willy-nilly, then your problem is one of testing the null hypothesis that the data were generated from one Normal distribution against the alternative that the data were generated by a mixture of two Normal distributions.  I believe that might have been addressed elsewhere here on CV: it comes down to conducting a simple likelihood ratio test (if you want to be formal) or examining a probability plot (for exploration).

Comment: @whuber: "unequal length" when your data explicitly are constituted by "pairs" - Ah yeah I guess that doesn't make sense. I am thinking of ahead for a generalisation of this, but never mind about that for now then.

Comment: @Christian Hennig: "Are you saying data are paired but you don't know what the pairs are?" I think let's say yes.

Comment: @whuber: Re: gaussian mixture: I thought about that, but it didn't seem right somehow? Like since my data comes in pairs I shouldn't model it in a way that means a "pair" might contain data from just one half of the mixture? Like X1 and X2 aren't ever samples from the same normal distribution, so I don't think I can model them as a mixture. Like suppose we have (X1,X2) as "one" sample and (Y1,Y2) as another sample. And I want to know if they come from the same pair of normal distributions. But I don't know which element of the pair should be matched with which element of the other pair.

Comment: @whuber: I could still do some likelihood-based testing, but I seem to have multiple hypotheses I need to test, and I don't think standard maximum likelihood ratio techniques are going to work for maximising over my hypotheses. It is going to violate all the assumptions of say Wilks' theorem etc because the hypotheses are some discrete combinatoric things, not continuous parameters.

Comment: Well, you *can* model your data as a mixture simply by ignoring the pairing.  The question is what is lost.  As far as I can see, the pairing is forcing the mixture weights both to equal $1/2.$  Thus, the pairing gives you one more degree of freedom, *but the rest of the analysis is the same.*

Comment: @whuber hmm, but how would it not affect the distributions, and ultimately p-values etc? Like the possible data is different, so I don't see how ignoring the pairing won't screw up the distribution. Like if we take five samples from a mixture distribution, they might all come from the same component of the mixture (though it is unlikely). But that's not something that can happen with paired samples.

Comment: Ignoring the pairing will make it harder to detect a difference -- but if you do detect a difference, that's not a problem.  But if your data truly are paired, then go ahead and use that fact in the way I described.